# Thread safe field value counting

Tags: django, orm, django-models, thread-safety

Is there any way to do something like this in django?

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES(1,(SELECT x.c2 FROM t x ORDER BY c2 DESC LIMIT 1)+1,1);
```

I have a model with many fields. And one of the field's value must be set with accordance to previous record.

Currently I am doing this by simple selecting previous record. But this is awful and not thread safe.

```
def save(self, *args, **kw):
    if self.sn is None or self.sn == ns.DEFAULT_GIFT_SN:
        q = Gift.objects.filter(company = self.company).only('id').order_by('-id')
        if q.count():
            last = q[0]
            next_id = int(last.sn) + 1
        else:
            next_id = 1
        self.sn = next_id
    super(Gift, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

I want to sth. lazy like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kw):
    if self.sn is None or self.sn == ns.DEFAULT_GIFT_SN:
        self.sn = _F('SELECT x.c2 FROM t x ORDER BY c2 DESC LIMIT 1')
    super(Gift, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE(for Cesar):**

```
class Gift(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    certificate = ChainedForeignKey(Certificate,
        chained_field = "company",
        chained_model_field = "company",
        show_all = False,
        auto_choose = True
    )
    gifter = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True)
    giftant_first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length = 30, blank = True)
    giftant_last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length = 30, blank = True)
    giftant_email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail address'), blank = True)
    giftant_mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()
    exp_date = models.DateTimeField()
    sn = models.CharField(max_length = 32, default = ns.DEFAULT_GIFT_SN, editable = False)
    pin_salt = models.CharField(max_length = 5, editable = False, default = gen_salt)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null = True, blank = True)
    postcard = models.ForeignKey(Postcard)
    state_status = models.IntegerField(choices = ns.STATE_STATUSES, default = ns.READY_STATE_STATUS)
    delivery_status = models.IntegerField(choices = ns.DELIVERY_STATUSES, default = ns.WAITING_DELIVERY_STATUS)
    payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = ns.PAYMENT_STATUSES, default = ns.NOT_PAID_PAYMENT_STATUS)
    usage_status = models.IntegerField(choices = ns.USAGE_STATUSES, default = ns.NOT_USED_USAGE_STATUS)
    nominal = models.FloatField(default = 0)
    used_money = models.FloatField(default = 0)
        use_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    cashier = ChainedForeignKey(CompanyUserProfile, blank = True, null = True,
        chained_field = "company",
        chained_model_field = "company",
        show_all = False,
        auto_choose = True
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('company', 'sn',)
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: Why not just set a default value of 1 for the 'sn' property and return a MAX on the ID of Gift, filtered by company? If MAX id > 1, then increment it by 1. Then you're returning a scalar value instead of hydrating objects.

Comment: @Brandon I agree with your idea, this will be better. But this does not solve problem of thread-safeness. If two threads will select max at the same time and than update. Both of them will have same value. Actually, this can be solved by locking, But I think it would be better to be able to update value at the moment of query.

Comment: As far as I know, there's not a good way the Django ORM can handle concurrency issues. If your app is highly transactional, you might want to handle this via a trigger on the db side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can do three things, from simple to outraging mad on the extremes:

1. Let `Gift.sn` be a `AutoField`, if you can get away without needing to increment the values separately for each company.
2. Use a `unique_together = ('company', 'sn')` constraint and update the gift instance if the uniqueness constraint fails, use the example @Stan provided, with the worst-case scenario that if you have a lot of concurrent writes only one will pass in each turn.
3. Write some custom SQL to obtain a lock on the `Gift` model table if the database supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I know `while` is evil but you can try something like that :

```
sn_is_ok = False
while not sn_is_ok:
    last_id = MyModel.objects.latest('id').id
    try:
        self.sn = last_id + 1
        self.save()
    Except IntegrityError:
        continue
    else:
        sn_is_ok = True
```

I don't think you get more that 2 loops.